ADO pipeline - how to create resources template that can be used by multiple pipelines?
I have multiple pipelines that all needs a specific pipeline as a resource, let's consider the below as one of the pipeline that uses pipeline resource.
trigger: none

resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: test
      project: Project
      source: test
      version: 1.2.3

stages:
  - stage: Validation
    jobs:
      - job: Validation
        steps:
          - script: echo "Validating"

When version of the resource pipeline(test) changes for example to 1.3.0, I need to update all the pipeline that uses this resource. So I was looking to create a resource template that can be used by all the pipelines and only the resource template needs to be updated for version change.
I came across this example Extend from a template with resources - I implemented it, but when I combine extends with stages I get this error:

Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML:
/Pipelines/test.yml (Line: 6, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'stages'

My implementation looks like this,
#resource-template.yml
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: test
      project: Project
      source: test
      version: 1.3.0

#test.yml
trigger: none

extends:
  template: Templates/_Shared/resource-template.yml

stages:
  - stage: Validation
    jobs:
      - job: Validation
        steps:
          - script: echo "Validating"

If I remove stages my implementation works good, but I need to use the stages in the main pipeline. Is there any different approach to handle this case?

A pipeline that uses extends cannot declare stages. As a stage is a minimum requirement for a pipeline, it is assumes that the pipeline you are extending already has stages.
You can pass in stages as parameters to your template, though:
# pipeline.yml
trigger: none

extends:
  template: resource-template.yml
  parameters:
    stages:
    - stage: ....

# resource-template
resources:
  pipelines
  - pipeline: test
    project: Project
    source: test
    version: 1.3.0

parameters:
- name: stages
  type: stageList

stages:
- ${{ parameters.stages }}


I want only the resources to be in the resource-template but not the stages as it would differ for each pipeline. Thanks for explaining about the extends, I get extends is not the right approach for my task, I'm looking for an alternate approach.

Extends can do exactly what you want, but you'd have to specify the stages as a parameter to the template
